# Return deferred.promise 2 services back

Tags: angularjs, factory, deferred

I have 3 services.

1. HttpSender - It controls the $http request

   ```
   app.service("HttpSender", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {

       this.send = function (path, method, params) {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $http({
               url: path,
               method: method,
               params: params
           }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               deferred.resolve(response.data);
           }, function errorCallback(response) {
               deferred.reject(response);
           });
           return deferred.promise;
       };

       this.sendRequestWithFile = function (path, method, params) {
           //todo check if needed
       };

   }]);
   ```
2. Api - controls all the api/ access token processes

   ```
     service("API", ["HttpSender", "$q", 'WindowOpen', function(HttpSender, $q, WindowOpen){

   var self = this;
    var API = {};

       API.requestTypes = {
           GetMethod: "GET",
           PostMethod: "POST",
           DeleteMethod: "DELETE",
           PutMethod: "PUT"
       };

           API.sendRequest = function (path, method, parameters, isCheckAccessToken)
           {
               path = ServersConfig.getApiServerUrl() + path;
               parameters.access_token = getAccessToken();
               HttpSender.send(path, method, parameters);
           };


           return API;

       }]);
   ```
3. Api - Endpoint which activate the api request

   ```
     app.factory('SelectedEndpoint', ['API', 

                  function (API) {

                   var getPath = function (campaign) {
                       return "/campaigns/" + campaign.id + '/content/selected';
                   };

                   return {
                       get: function (campaign) {
                           API.sendRequest(getPath(campaign),  API.requestTypes.GetMethod, {}, true).then(function (content) {


                           });
                       }
                   };


             }]);
   ```

How can return the deferred.promise to the endpoint function so the then will get the answer? The following process only works if i add then also in the api factory the then return it to the endpoint

Comment: Could you add an example of how you would expect to use this?

Comment: I want to return it straight to the controller. I just minimize the process for the question. I just want to return the data that is being returned not to the caller but to previous previous caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can return the deferred.promise to the endpoint function so the then will get the answer?

By properly returning promises on each step.

**1.** `HttpSender` service. Do not use deferred here, just return promise directly:

```
app.service("HttpSender", ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {

  this.send = function(path, method, params) {
    return $http({
      url: path,
      method: method,
      params: params
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

}]);
```

**2.** `Api` service. Make sure you return previous promise with `return HttpSender.send(path, method, parameters);`:

```
 service("API", ["HttpSender", "$q", 'WindowOpen', function(HttpSender, $q, WindowOpen) {

  var self = this;
  var API = {};

  API.requestTypes = {
    GetMethod: "GET",
    PostMethod: "POST",
    DeleteMethod: "DELETE",
    PutMethod: "PUT"
  };

  API.sendRequest = function(path, method, parameters, isCheckAccessToken) {
    path = ServersConfig.getApiServerUrl() + path;
    parameters.access_token = getAccessToken();
    return HttpSender.send(path, method, parameters); // note return promise
  };

  return API;

}]);
```

Comment: It still not return the result to the  API.sendRequest(getPath(campaign),  API.requestTypes.GetMethod, {}, true).then(function (content) {

 });

Comment: It gives me an error for the use of the then on the sendRequest function

Comment: did you add `return` from `API.sendRequest`?

Comment: Very well. Didn't saw that. Thanks